# NSJSONSerialization parsng special characters

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsjsonserialization

I am parsing some data using `NSJSONSerialization`. After parsing, I get strings like `&auml ;` and `%#339;` which i think has something to do with encoding. But `NSJSONSerialzation` doesn't ask for what encoding it requires, it i guess detects it by itself. So my question is, how can I get proper strings instead of these weird `&auml ;` and `%#339;`.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with character encoding, those are _HTML entities_. I'm too lazy right now to really answer your question but this might give you the right thing to search for.

Answer (score 1):

`NSJSONSerialization` assumes the encoding is one of the Unicode encodings.  Make sure the data you pass to it is in UTF-8 (or UTF-16).  ä is C3 A4 in UTF-8 or E4 in UTF-16.

Note that the default encoding for HTTP if none is specified is ISO-8859-1, so it may be that you are passing ISO-8859-1 data instead of UTF-8.

Answer (score -1):

In `options` try NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves, it must return NSMutableString.. For more take a look at the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).